# HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException (Not caused by out of memory)

Tags: hazelcast

So we have been having a lot of issues with embedded Hazelcast stability in production. After the application with the embedded hazelcast instance has been running for a while (sometimes hours, sometimes a couple days; which leads me to believe it is load related), Hazelcast goes down and the logs start getting spammed with:

```
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is no
t active!
        at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.getService(AbstractDistri
butedObject.java:93) ~[hinata.jar:3.0.49]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toData(MapProxySupport.j
ava:1046) ~[hinata.jar:3.0.49]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:83) ~[hinata.jar:3.0.49]
```

Unfortunately, I can't post the entire stack trace as it contains references to proprietary code, but this much should be sufficient to get the point across.

After much searching, it seasm everyone who is also seeing `OutOfMemoryExceptions`. In our case, we are not seeing this and our memory seems to be more than sufficient for load after some monitoring.

I can't seem to find any documentation on when this exception can be thrown other than when memory is low.

I am looking for knowledge on what cases this exception can be thrown or where else to look for Hazelcast stability issues.